# Usage of facebook Folly

Tags: c++, folly

I'm on MacOS and with g++-11. Folly successfully builds and when I try to run a piece of code from the test file executors/test/ExecutorWithPriorityTest.cpp, the compiler says

```
/Users/tannyxie/Documents/Project Preparation/github/folly_include/installed/folly/include/folly/FBString.h:2753:8: error: 'fmt' has not been declared
 2753 | struct fmt::formatter<folly::fbstring> : private formatter<fmt::string_view> {
      |        ^~~
/Users/tannyxie/Documents/Project Preparation/github/folly_include/installed/folly/include/folly/FBString.h:2753:22: error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token
 2753 | struct fmt::formatter<folly::fbstring> : private formatter<fmt::string_view> {
      |                      ^
```

This is the code I run.

```
#include <folly/executors/ExecutorWithPriority.h>
  
#include <folly/executors/CPUThreadPoolExecutor.h>
#include <folly/futures/Future.h>
#include <folly/portability/GTest.h>

using namespace folly;

int main() {
  bool tookLopri = false;
  auto completed = 0;
  auto hipri = [&] {
    EXPECT_FALSE(tookLopri);
    completed++;
  };
  auto lopri = [&] {
    tookLopri = true;
    completed++;
  };
  auto pool = std::make_shared<CPUThreadPoolExecutor>(
      0 /*numThreads*/, 2 /*numPriorities*/);
  {
    auto loPriExecutor = ExecutorWithPriority::create(
        getKeepAliveToken(pool.get()), Executor::LO_PRI);
    auto hiPriExecutor = ExecutorWithPriority::create(
        getKeepAliveToken(pool.get()), Executor::HI_PRI);
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      loPriExecutor->add(lopri);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      hiPriExecutor->add(hipri);
    }
    pool->setNumThreads(1);
  }
  pool->join();
}
```

I compiled it with command `g++-11 folly.cpp`.

Am I missing any header file? Or should I add some command line flag?

Comment: Do you have, or need to include, [libfmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt)? `fmt::` is the namespace for libfmt, and `fmt::formatter`, `fmt::string_view` are both libfmt types -- so it seems you are missing some sort of dependency to it

Comment: @Eljay it is not a dupe of this.

Comment: `FBString.h` has the required `#include <fmt/format.h>`. (Or at least the master version on github does; check yours). Since the compiler doesn't complain about the missing include file, it exists and can be found. The question is, what does your file contain? Do `g++-11 folly.cpp -H` and see where each include file, including fmt/format.h, comes from. Examine it. Does it contain `namespace fmt`? Do `g++-11 -E folly.cpp`. Does the output contain `namespace fmt`?

Comment: I added the path of fmt into CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH and it no longer gives that error. It's now complaining `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`. I guess it's still about the fmt library as when I run a simple fmt::print, it gives the same error. And in folly library, it says ```#if FMT_VERSION >= 70000
namespace fmt {
template <>
struct formatter<folly::StringPiece> : private formatter<string_view> {...};
}
#endif```

Comment: @ n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. `g++-11 -E` shows it contains `namespace fmt`.